# Define start and stop for recursive formula

Tags: recursive-algorithms, wolfram-alpha

A recursive formula like a_{n} = a_{n-1}+4, how is it specified where to start and stop? In any computer language, I'd write something `for(uint i =0; i<stop; i++) {}`. With a calculator for example, how would "get result for a_{5}" be stated, or, just how is it written in standard math notation?

Comment: I recommend moving your question to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ah good point. will ask there once 40 minutes have passed. But, was also thinking more generally, in standard math notation. seems like it might be what wolfram alpha uses too. updated question to be math general.

Comment: mostly how calculators/computers tend to read command for start stop. but I did like Greg Martin said, and got some sort of answer to initial question there. rsolve[] or recursiveTable[]. guess this can be closed if anyone thinks it should be. thanks for the help.